# How do I encourage risk-taking in a feedfoward neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, loss-function, feed-forward

I am doing my first real dive into Neural Networks, and I am trying to construct the classic "number-identification network" without any outside databases. After some initial testing, I have been running into the issue of my network keeping all weights incredibly low so that the outputs are all nearly zero. I see why this happens (every time the program gets 9 out of the 10 outputs correct!) but obviously this is something I need to discourage from happening.

Does anybody have tips on how I could fix this? I am using a sigmoid activation function and cross-entropy cost function for a feedforward neural network, and I am wondering whether there are better choices to make the program consider the error in the correct digit more significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [momentum](https://engmrk.com/gradient-descent-with-momentum/) and [learning rate](https://machinelearningmastery.com/understand-the-dynamics-of-learning-rate-on-deep-learning-neural-networks/) to boost exploration of gradient descent optimization algorithm and use weights to boost the contribution of the minority class samples to the loss function through multiplying calculated gradients by the weights. For your sigmoid activation function and cross-entropy cost function, you can implement it like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits).

> labels * -log(sigmoid(logits)) * pos_weight +
>       (1 - labels) * -log(1 - sigmoid(logits))